# Setting Link To Open In App

Tags: android

I am developing an Android application which uses WebView, and I would like to open a link in the app. The problem I have come across is that each of our customers use a different URL and is set via a preference in the android application. From, what I understand you have to set a link in the android manifest. Is this still achievable to have a link open in the application?

Comment: You want to open application from web view URL ?

Comment: `The problem I have come across is that each of our customers use a different URL and is set via a preference in the android application.` Can you simplify this line

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. We have a platform for service and sales that we install at a customer's location. A user could get an e-mail with a link to the web application we have installed on site. What we are hoping to accomplish is to have the URL in the e-mail open in the application. Where I have hit a snag is the URL for customer A may be something.customer1.com and customer b may be somehting.customer2.com. I am trying to get external links to open the Android application if it is installed and user gives permission of course.

Answer (score 0):

In order to open a link in the app just make sure to have an `Activity` that has a `WebView` on its layout. Then, in your activity do something like this:

```
WebView webview = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.your_web_view);
webview.loadUrl("http://your.url/");
```

Just read the user preference that stores the URL before calling `loadUrl()` and you're all set

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a `webview` and give it an id. And then do this in your code:

```
//Identify the webview
WebView web_view = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.web_view);

//start web client
web_view.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());

//Load URL
web_view.loadUrl("your url");
```

And don't forget to add this line in your AndroidManifest.xml file :

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Hope it works!! :)